Loadrunner is not opening properly
When try to open the Virtual generator user(Loadrunner).I got below Error.Can you someone help me to solve the problem.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CF405F74-C2F7-4814-AD81-525877D8C9A0} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
System.BadImageFormatException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CF405F74-C2F7-4814-AD81-525877D8C9A0} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).
Fix this problem and Open Loadrunner application.

a) Are you running as Admin?
b) I assume you have a support agreement. What has OpenText support suggested?
